# Encountering 'urlparse module not found' error while importing googleanalytics library in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-analytics, jupyter-notebook, urlparse

I am working on a project where I need to use the Google Analytics API to extract data into a python notebook.

I installed the googleanalytics library using:

`!pip install googleanalytics`

and it successfully installed.

Then I tried importing the library using:

`import googleanalytics as ga`

but it gives me a ModuleNotFound error which shows:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlparse'

I then checked which library urlparse belongs to and found that it is a part of urllib3 library. So I tried installing that library but I got a message that it is already installed.

So I separately tried importing urlparse to check if it works using:

`from urllib.parse import urlparse`

and it works.

**In summary**, the urlparse module is installed but when I import googleanalytics library, I get an error that says module is not found.

How can that be fixed?

Comment: what is your Python version?

Comment: I would recommend not to use this package since the last commit on it was 5 years ago. Have a look at [this guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py) instead.

Comment: ```@SanidhyaSingh``` - I'm using Python 3.9.12